# Flow: Use new type for variable?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

I have a simple new class X which holds some results of a callout to an external system.
In a flow I need a variable of type X. Is there any way to declare a variable of that new type in a flow?

My new class is:

```
public class FooCalloutResult {
    public Boolean success;
    public Map<Id, Boolean> results;
    public List<String> messages;

    public FooCalloutResult() {
        success = false;
        results = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
        messages = new List<String>();      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get some data in a flow from an apex class you need to have an Process Invocable method - this is done by adding the @InvocableMethod annotation.

Example:

```
global class lookUpAccountAnnotation {

   @InvocableMethod
   public static List<String> getAccountIds(List<String> names) {

      List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
      List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name in :names];
      for (Account account : accounts) {
         accountIds.add(account.Id);
      }
      return accountIds;
   }
}
```

With this annotation the class will appear in your list of available elements in the Flow and you need to put the Input and Output that will go into it.

Depending on what kind of operation you want to do you might need to use the Process.plugin interface instead. Please check this article to see which option supports what kind of data to decide on what you need - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_elements_apex.htm&type=5